# Problem in changing String to date in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i am using following code but the long values are not same any one can help me .

```
{
     long longCurrentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Current time is..."+longCurrentTime);
     Date date=new Date(longCurrentTime);
     SimpleDateFormat dformat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
     String inStringTime=dformat.format(date);
     long byStringLongValue=HttpDateParser.parse(inStringTime);
     System.out.println("String to long conversion..."+byStringLongValue);

  }
```

in this code both long values are coming different.

thanks

Comment: java tag was missing. i am surprised since no answers for this simple question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your *date format* **ignores** the `millisecond` part.

Add the milliseconds part and verify the result.

```
 SimpleDateFormat dformat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss S");
                                                                         ^^^^
```